# AWS SNS - Creating a Platform Endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, push-notification, aws-sdk

```
 public async Task<string> CreatePushEndpoint(string deviceToken,string platformApplicationArn )
 {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceToken))
            throw new Exception("Required parameters missing");
        var publishRequest = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest()
        {
            PlatformApplicationArn = platformApplicationArn ,
            Token = deviceToken                
        };
        var resp = await _client.CreatePlatformEndpointAsync(publishRequest);
        return resp.EndpointArn;
  }
```

This is my code for creating a Platform Endpoint. But this not working. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: what kind of problem do you have? Error, nothing happens....

Comment: no errors.. do not get a response.

Comment: your code seems ok, I have the same code in my java code and it works without any problem. Are you using the last version of the aws sdk?